# Polymer 1.x: Two-way databinding for paper-dropdown-menu

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements, jsbin

I want to set the `paper-dropdown-menu` to the value of `'Three'` upon loading. I want to do this by data binding the value attribute of the `paper-dropdown-menu` to a sub property of the element called `item.number` which is set when registering the element. When I attempt this using the below code, the result I see is that the `paper-dropdown-menu` displayed value is just blank instead of reading 'Three'.

What code changes will achieve my desired behavior?

Follow these steps to reproduce the problem.

1. [Open this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/loceqayezo/1/edit?html,console,output).
2. Note the content of the display value of the dropdown menu is blank.
3. Click the button labeled <kbd>Click to show item</kbd>
4. Observe the console prints:

   > [object Object] {
   >   number: "Three"
   >   }
5. Understand the above steps demonstrate my desired behavior is not occurring.
6. Select the number "Four" in the dropdown menu.
7. Click the button labeled <kbd>Click to show item</kbd>
8. Observe the console prints:

   > [object Object] {
   >   number: "Four"
   >   }
9. Understand the above step shows one-way data binding is working on the element.

How can I achieve my desired behavior?

http://jsbin.com/loceqayezo/1/edit?html,console,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-item/paper-item.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style></style>

  <p>
    <button on-tap="show">Click to show item</button>
  </p>

  <paper-dropdown-menu label="Numbers"
                       value="{{item.number}}">
    <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
      <paper-item>One</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Two</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Three</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Four</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
  </paper-dropdown-menu>


</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {
        item: {
          type: Object,
          notify: true,
          value: function() {
            return {number: "Three"};
          },
        },
      },
      show: function() {
        console.log('item', this.item);
      },
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```

Comment: [Here is a JS bin of the accepted working answer](http://jsbin.com/nemelawoxi/edit?html,console,output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because value property of `<paper-dropdown-menu>` is read-only. See the [documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu).

Instead you can bind to `<paper-listbox selected>`. With minimal changes you will have to bind to dropdown's element index.

```js
Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {
        item: {
          type: Object,
          notify: true,
          value: function() {
            return {number: 2};
          },
        },
      },
      show: function() {
        console.log('item', this.item);
      },
    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-item/paper-item.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style></style>

  <p>
    <button on-tap="show">Click to show item</button>
  </p>

  <paper-dropdown-menu label="Numbers">
    <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" 
                   selected="{{item.number}}">
      <paper-item>One</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Two</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Three</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Four</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
  </paper-dropdown-menu>
  

</template>
</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```

To keep the full name in your `item` you can add an attribute to you selectable elements and use the `attrForSelected` property of `paper-listbox`.

```js
Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {
        item: {
          type: Object,
          notify: true,
          value: function() {
            return {number: "Three"};
          },
        },
      },
      show: function() {
        console.log('item', this.item);
      },
    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-item/paper-item.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style></style>

  <p>
    <button on-tap="show">Click to show item</button>
  </p>

  <paper-dropdown-menu label="Numbers">
    <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" 
                   selected="{{item.number}}"
                   attr-for-selected="data-item">
      <paper-item data-item="One">One</paper-item>
      <paper-item data-item="Two">Two</paper-item>
      <paper-item data-item="Three">Three</paper-item>
      <paper-item data-item="Four">Four</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
  </paper-dropdown-menu>
  

</template>
</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```